# Convert 2D numpy array into pandas pivot table

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, pivot-table

I have a 2D numpy array representing depth on grid of coordinates.

```
z = np.array([[100, 101, 102, 103],
              [101, 102, 103, 104],
              [102, 103, 104, 105],
              [103, 104, 105, 106],
              [104, 105, 106, 107]])
```

I also have a 1D numpy array listing the vertical coordinates and another 1D numpy array listing the horizontal coordinates.

```
x = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13])
y = np.array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

In some cases, this data is provided as a list of 'x  y  z' data e.g.:

```
10  20  100
10  21  101
10  22  102
10  23  103
10  24  104
11  20  101
11  21  102
...
12  23  105
12  24  106
13  20  103
13  21  104
13  22  105
13  23  106
13  24  107
```

In this case creating a pivot table is trivial....

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'z'], delim_whitespace=True)
pvt = data.pivot_table(values='z', index='y', columns='x', fill_value=-100000)
```

How can I create a pivot table with the same labels, format etc starting with the data in three arrays?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
pd.DataFrame(z, index=y, columns=x)
```

?

It seems to me that you essentially want a DataFrame and just using a pivot_table because it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a way using numpy array functions to get the data in the correct format. It's a valid answer but I hoped there was a more elegant way to do it with pandas.

Since I can already pivot from the DataFrame returned by `read_csv()`, the simplest option is to get the data in the same format as the read DataFrame...

```
zf = z.flatten()
xr = np.repeat(x, y.size)
yt = np.tile(y, x.size)
d = np.stack((xr, yt, zf), axis=-1)
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
pvt = data.pivot_table(values='z', index='y', columns='x')
```